A very tight fit
Can the expression "a very tight fit" be used in the text below to express difficulty in obtaining something, in this case, an invitation to attend a lecture?
My philosophy professor will be giving a lecture on ethics and tolerance tomorrow night to a small group at our college. It will be a very tight fit, but if you're interested, I can get you an invitation.

Not really. "A tight fit" is an expression which usually means either that there are no gaps/space around something, such as a wooden peg in a hole, or it could be used to describe the situation where someone's clothing is almost too tight to fit them properly, or it could used when talking about a small space where there is no room for anything larger.

Please fix your title: fit not feet. Thanks. There were six people in the car, which was a tight fit. It describes physical space for some number of people.

Could be a chigger complained of lack of room in small feet, but it would be no great feat to fix that title.

Thanks Lambie, I just fixed the title. What I was trying to say with the text was that there would be few places available to attend the lecture, and it was not clear whether this was because of the small space available (a small room, for example), or perhaps because the professor wanted to restrict his audience to a small number of people.

Well, if the professor was doing the restricting it does not work. If the space is too small, it does work. :)

Worth noting that "a very tight fit" could work here if the tight fit referred to time management. Though you'd definitely want to specify that to avoid confusion.

Thanks Lambie and fatalerrer. Please, fatalerrer, "time management" here would mean something like there would be little time to try to get the invitation, maybe the talk was just a few hours away, or something like that?

The only situation where this would work is if the reason it is hard to get an invitation is that the room is too crowded (people literally squeezing in tightly). And a situation like that might violate fire safety rules.
Otherwise, it would be better to say something like “it will be tough” or “it will be a longshot.”
